# Mostrar variable de phpmyadmin en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero que al editar la variable desde el phpmyadmin cambie acá. espero explicarme, porque no se como explicarlo.

```
echo '$' . $rows_dbpartidos['color_local'] . '';
```

y se muestre un codigo que ya tengo organizado, por ejemplo, "$celeste" tiene este RGB: 40, 180, 228

Edito, tengo este código:

```html
COLORES.PHP
<?php
$rojo='198, 39, 58';
$azul='33, 62, 113';
$verde='14, 108, 57';
$negro='28, 28, 28';
$granate='123, 43, 63';
$celeste='40, 180, 228';

?>

Y donde quiero poner la variable para editar el codigo lo tengo asi:
<?php
include('colores.php'); 

?>
```

```html
                          <svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;position: absolute;">
                              <line x1="15%" y1="110%" x2="70%" y2="-10%" style="stroke:rgb(<?php 
                          $sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from equipos where id=1";
                          $result_dbpartidos = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbpartidos);
                          $rows_dbpartidos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbpartidos);
                          if($rows_dbpartidos){    
                              echo'' . $rows_dbpartidos['color_local'] .  '';
}
                                ?>);stroke-width:40"></line>
                          </svg>
```

Y en el echo quiero poner la variable editable.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82081/discussion-on-question-by-matiphp-mostrar-variable-de-phpmyadmin-en-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP permite el uso de **variables variables**, o dicho de otro modo, nombres de variables que se pueden definir y usar dinámicamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
echo "$a $$a"; // hola mundo
echo "$a $hola"; // hola mundo
```

Una variable variable toma el valor de una variable y lo trata como el nombre de una variable. En el ejemplo anterior, hola, se puede usar como el nombre de una variable **utilizando dos signos de dólar**.

Para usar variables variables con arrays como es el caso, hay que resolver un problema de ambigüedad, por lo que hay que determinar a cual de las dos variables hace referencia el índice que indiquemos, para esto utilizamos las llaves:

```
${$a[1]} // pertenece a la variable que da nombre a la variable
${$a}[1] // pertenece a la variable después de haber resuelto el nombre
```

Dado que tu tienes el nombre de la variable que contiene el valor que quieres en un Array puedes hacer algo así

```
echo ${$rows_dbpartidos['color_local']};
```

Cómo nota adicional las variables se pueden encadenar y hacer cosas estrañanas pero válidas como esta, en que aparece en las notas del manual.

```
$Bar = "a";
$Foo = "Bar";
$World = "Foo";
$Hello = "World";
$a = "Hello";

$a;       //Returns Hello
$$a;      //Returns World
$$$a;     //Returns Foo
$$$$a;    //Returns Bar
$$$$$a;   //Returns a
$$$$$$a;  //Returns Hello
$$$$$$$a; //Returns World
```

Comment: Gracias, eso funcionó, tarde en responder porque estaba con otro problema y no lo probé, ahora ya funciona, igual es recomendable actualizar muy seguido esa variable de "color"